# PHP function doesn't work with variables

Tags: php, function, variables, sorting

Hi I have the following function:

```
foreach($array_1 as &$arr){
usort($arr,"cmp");
}

function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a[2] == $b[2]) {
    return 0;
    }
    return ($a[2] < $b[2]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

If I do it like this it works, but if I put a variable instead of 2 which == 2 and a number the function doesn't work. Why is this and how can I work around it? I want to be able to change the number to sort an array based on variable input.

The code that doesn't work is:

```
$type = 2;
foreach($array_1 as &$arr){
usort($arr,"cmp");
}

function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a[$type] == $b[$type]) {
    return 0;
    }
    return ($a[$type] < $b[$type]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you show it as you have it when it doesn't work?

Comment: Well, show us the code that *doesn't* work.

Comment: Take a look at example #4 of the usort man page http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PHP 5.3+, which hopefully you should be using, the solution is simple using a closure:

```
$index = 2;

foreach ($array_1 as &$arr) {
    usort($arr, function ($a, $b) use ($index) {
        return $a[$index] - $b[$index];
    });
}
```

For PHP 5.2-, you could use `global` variables (**YUCK!!**) or a class:

```
class Sort {

    protected $index;

    public function __construct($index) {
        $this->index = $index;
    }

    public function compare($a, $b) {
        return $a[$this->index] - $b[$this->index];
    }

}

$index = 2;

foreach ($array_1 as &$arr) {
    usort($arr, array(new Sort($index), 'compare'));
}
```

Comment: it's 5.2.17 so perhaps your second suggestion will be usefull

Comment: Wow I changed the index value to the variable and it works! Thank you SO MUCH I've been stuck with this for quite some time!